# Tkinter Label Won't update / Listview + Button

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, label

I'm very new to programming! Only did HTML stuff so far and I started working with Python and Tkinter. I'm trying to make a program using Tkinter that shows a `List`. You select something, press a button, and in another `Label` it should show a text + the selection.

I'm having trouble updating the label though. Hope the following is enough information:

```
us2 = Label(fr3, textvariable= auswahlinfo + "auswahlinfo Variable geht \n noch nicht...",
                font=("TkDefaultFont", 12), pady=5, width=30, height=10, relief="sunken", bg="white")

    us2.pack(side="top")

def OnReleaseClick(self, event, auswahlinfo, fr3, us2):
    widget = event.widget
    selection = widget.curselection()
    value = widget.get(selection[0])
    us2.auswahlinfo.set("Auswahl:", selection, ": '%s'" % value)
```

Comment: Do you get error message? Show it.

Comment: I see three suspicious things. First: `us2.auswahlinfo.get()` - shouldn't be `auswahlinfo.get()`. Second: arguments in `OnReleaseClick()` - show how you assign this function to button. Third: `textvariable= auswahlinfo + "some text"` - `textvariable` expects `StringVar` (or similar), and you can't add `StringVar` and normal string.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this is what you're looking for:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()

def selectFunc(event):
    selectedLine = lbox.curselection()
    lineNum = selectedLine[0]
    lineTxt = lbox.get(lineNum)
    labelTxt = "You chose " + lineTxt
    lbl.config(text=labelTxt)

lbox = Listbox(root)
lbox.pack()
lbox.insert(END, "First Line")
lbox.insert(END, "Second Line")
lbox.insert(END, "Third Line")
lbox.bind("<<ListboxSelect>>", selectFunc)

lbl = Label(root)
lbl.pack()
```

I think the code itself is self-explanatory, but since you are a beginner (as you mentioned above), it's pretty normal if you don't get something (please don't get me wrong. Actually, I'm a beginner too). So please don't hesitate to ask anything you didn't get. It would be pleasure to explain any part of the code.